# Is there a Generic type to use with Binary types in JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, db2

I have a generic java program that exports data from Oracle and DB2 tables to text files.

For all types I use rs.getString() function on the ResultSet to extract data. It does work for all types except CLOB, BLOB and binary types. For example, It gives the exception with Oracle :

> Invalid column type: getString not implemented for class
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CBlobAccessor

The question : Is there a generic type I can use in my program to extract CLOB, BLOC and Binary types usable with both Oracle and DB2 ?

Something like :

```
GenericType obj = rs.getGenericType("column_name");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `getObject("column_name")` and, based on the type, cast it to the right thing.